# ASP.NET Core MVC routing parameter in Home/Index

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a question about ASP.NET Core MVC routing. I have a default routing definition and I can access to home page with follow routing.

```
/Home/Index/123
/Home/Index
/Home
/
```

But I need to process /123
For example:  **[www.mypage.com/123](http://www.mypage.com/123)**

and not **[www.mypage.com/?id=123](http://www.mypage.com/?id=123)** or **[www.mypage.com/home/index/123](http://www.mypage.com/home/index/123)**

I can't configure my routing configuration to accomplish my goal :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following routing attributes:

```
[Route("Home/Index/{id?}")] // http://localhost:4935/home/index or http://localhost:4935/home/index/7
[Route("Index/{id}")] // http://localhost:4935/Index/5555     
[Route("{id?}")]  // http://localhost:4935/7777 or http://localhost:4935/  
public IActionResult Index(int? id)
{
    return View((object)id);       
}
```

The view:

```
@model int?
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Model.HasValue ? Model.ToString() : "< No Id > ";    
}
@* 
   The view content 
*@
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I tried before the message but without the last one, that is the key.